# querying a DB for an unknown element with a given uuid

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lot of years ago, I discussed with some neo4j engineers about the ability to query an unknown object given it's uuid.

At that time, the answer was that there was no general db index in neo4j.

Now, I have the same problem to solve:

each node I create has an unique id (uuid in the form ***<nx:u-<uuid>-?v=n>*** where ns is the namespace, uuid is a unique uuid and v=n is the version number of the element.

I'd like to have the ability to run the following cypher query:

```
match (n) where n.about = 'ki:u-SSD-v5.0?v=2' return n;
```

which actually return nothing.

The following query

```
match (n:'mm:ontology') where n.about = 'ki:u-SSD-v5.0?v=2' return n;
```

returns what I need, despite the fact that at query time I don't know the element type.

Can anyone help on this?

Paolo

Comment: is `uuid+version` unique or could multiple namespaces have the same `uuid+version`?

Comment: namespace + uid+version is unique. 
Of course, if namespace is not expanded, there is the possibility of duplication, but we can think of it as unique.

Should be nice to have the ability to expand a namespace to build the correspondent IRI and use it as a index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered adding a achema index to every node in the database for the `about` attribute?

For instance

Add a *global* label to all nodes in the graph (e.g. Node) that do not already have it.  If your graph is overly large and/or heap overly small you will need to batch this operation. Something along the lines of the following...

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n:Node
WITH n
LIMIT 100000
SET n:Node
```

After the label is added then create an index on the `about` attribute for your new *global* label (e.g. Node). These steps can be performed interchangeably as well.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:Node) assert node.about IS UNIQUE
```

Then querying with something like the following

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE n.about = 'ki:u-SSD-v5.0?v=2' 
RETURN n;
```

will return the node you are seeking in a performant manner.

Comment: But doesn't run ;-(

Comment: Did you add the `Node` label to all of your nodes?

Comment: Yes, all the nodes have an about label, as they comes from an rdf:Owl ontology, and about in Owl has the same role of uuid (not so easy, but accept the concept!).

So, now I have the following elements loaded in my DB:
`create constraint on (node:Node) assert node.about is unique;`
`create (_ki_u_SSD_v5_0_v_2:`mm:ontology` { about: 'ki:u-SSD-v5.0?v=2', label: 'SSD-v5.0', collectionName: '/db/apps/ssd/ontology/public/SSD-v5.0', hasVersion: '2', decoded: 'true', hasCreationDate : '2013-04-11T18:09:45.735+02:00', label_it_IT : 'SSD-v5.0' });`

Comment: But the query 
`match (sub:Node) where sub.about = 'ki:u-SSD-v5.0?v=2' return sub;`
returns an empty set, while the query 
`MATCH (n:`mm:ontology`) RETURN n`
return the expected record.

Comment: if you type `:schema` in the browser what is returned?

Comment: Indexes
       ON :Node(about) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
       ON :mm:ontology(about) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
       .......

    Constraints
       ON ( `mm:ontology`:`mm:ontology` ) ASSERT `mm:ontology`.about IS UNIQUE
       ON ( node:Node ) ASSERT node.about IS UNIQUE
       .....

Comment: yep - definitely won't work without the label. Without the label your query wouldn't match anything. I added a little extra to the answer to clear that up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147640/discussion-between-paolo-di-pietro-and-dave-bennett).